# How to check if boolean is true or false and update value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, checkbox, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two related models - Tour & Reservation. Tour has an "amount" attribute. I'm using a checkbox to determine whether the amount gets changed based on user input (checkboxes). The default value is set to false.

**Goal:**
I want the @tour.amount to change ONLY when either of the checkboxes are ticked. I have the following, but it charges the extra amount regardless if the checkboxes are checked or not. What am I missing? I tried comparing the params to 0, "0", true to no avail.

```
if @reservation.update_attribute(:option1, params[:option1]) == true || @reservation.update_attribute(:option2, params[:option2]) == true
   @tour.amount = @tour.amount + 1500
else
   @tour.amount = @tour.amount
end
```

**Params:**

```
Params (unchecked)
"option 1"=>"0", "option 2"=>"0"
Params (checked)
"option 1"=>"0", "option 2"=>"0"
```

**Controller:**

```
 def new
    @reservation = Reservation.new
    @tour = Tour.find(params[:tour_id])
  end

 def create
    @tour = Tour.find(params[:tour_id])
    @reservation = Reservation.new(reservation_params)

    if @reservation.update_attribute(:option1, params[:option1]) == true || @reservation.update_attribute(:option2, params[:option2]) == true
       @tour.amount = @tour.amount + 1500
    else
       @tour.amount = @tour.amount
    end

    if @reservation.save
      Stripe::Charge.create(
        :amount => @tour.amount, # amount in cents, again
        :currency => "usd",
        :card => params[:stripeToken]
      )
      flash[:success] = "Your reservation has been booked for #{@reservation.passengers} person(s). Please save this info."
      redirect_to new_tour_reservation_path(@tour)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

SOLUTION:
(Don't overthink so much!)

```
if @reservation.option1 == true && @reservation.option2 == true
       @tour.amount = @tour.amount + 3000
    elsif @reservation.option1 == true
       @tour.amount = @tour.amount + 1500
    elsif @reservation.option2 == true
       @tour.amount = @tour.amount + 1500
    else
       @tour.amount = @tour.amount
    end
```

Comment: You're checking if the update_attribute call succeeds not if the param is either true or false.

Comment: Wow, okay.. clearly I was overthinking it. I have updated my original question with the solution code. I know it's very messy, so any suggestions/feedback will be more than welcome! Thank you so much!

Comment: You don't really need the last else, as you're just setting the value to the same value. Also, in Ruby, you can just do `if @reservation.option1`, no need for `== true`

Comment: I added an answer, although it's not very thorough.

Comment: Great, thanks so much! I have marked your solution as the answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking if the update_attribute call succeeds not if the param is either true or false.